# RoR Question: Where's script/server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following Head First Ruby, and found out that the `server` file inside the `script` folder of my first project is missing. I followed [this Ubuntu installation tutorial](http://www.pablasso.com/2009/01/12/%C2%BFcomo-instalar-ruby-on-rails-en-ubuntu) (sorry, Spanish link, still should be easy to follow the commands) and I guess some files/packages are missing. How I can get them?

```
antonio@antonio-desktop:~/Documents/tickets$ ruby script/server
ruby: No such file or directory -- script/server (LoadError)
antonio@antonio-desktop:~/Documents/tickets$ ls
app     config.ru  doc      lib  public    README  test  vendor
config  db         Gemfile  log  Rakefile  script  tmp
antonio@antonio-desktop:~/Documents/tickets$ cd script
antonio@antonio-desktop:~/Documents/tickets/script$ ls
rails
```

Comment: Rails version? In rails 3.x there isn't a script/server file...

Comment: @lucapette: Its Rails 3.1. You think should I dump the book and read straight out of the documentation? Have significant changes occurred? The command to create the project has changed from what appears on the book.

Comment: Rails 2.X and Rails 3.x are different in many things. So, if you're starting now go straight to official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running Rails 3, it's now:

```
./script/rails server
```

All of the separate rails scripts in the scripts directory run through the single ./script/rails dispatcher now.  This works for the console and other things you may be looking for as well (ie: ./script/rails console).

Comment: Thanks, I guess the book is outdated.

Comment: If you haven't yet, you will need to run bundle install as that error explained.  You may want to run Rails 2.3.x with this tutorial.

Comment: `rails server` as well as `rails s` will also start the server.

Comment: I ran bundle install and it failed, please see my following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264199/ror-install-run-bundle-install-not-working