# RoR install: Run 'bundle install' not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While trying to run a first project on Ubuntu 10.10 I got this:

```
antonio@antonio-desktop:~/Documents/tickets$./script/rails server
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Well, afterwards I write:

```
antonio@antonio-desktop:~/Documents/tickets$ bundle install
```

and get this in the middle of the installation process:

```
        /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

So, I tried this:

```
 sudo yum install sqlite3-devel
```

And got this:

```
 Setting up Install Process
    No package sqlite3-devel available.
    Nothing to do
```

Why? I'm running Rails 3.1, btw.

Answer (score 3):

try: `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `yum`, I went ahead and guessed that you're on Fedora. I then Googled "fedora sqlite3" and found a [blog post](http://radicallyrails.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-install-sqlite3-on-fedora.html) that recommends this:

```
sudo yum install sqlite-devel
```

Sounds like the gem doesn't have the package name quite right. Give this one a go :)

Comment: Actually, I'm using Ubuntu 10.10. Wrote it on the first line of the post.

Comment: that yum call got me the same output as the one I wrote: No package sqlite-devel available.
Nothing to do

Comment: try:
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev

Comment: I'm posting it as an answer so this question can have a valid answer on record.